# SQL Count from 2 tables

Tags: sql

Background: There are multiple DBPArentProductKEys associated with a POG.ID.

I need to count the number of Pog.DBKEYs that occurs. Right now the results count total POG.IDs in the total database for value4, but I want the count associated with the DBparentproductkey.

```
select distinct 
    Count(pog.DBKey) as Total,
    pos.DBParentProductKey 
from
    ix_spc_planogram as pog with (nolock), ix_spc_position as pos with (nolock), 
    ix_spc_product as pro with (nolock) 
where 
    pog.dbkey = pos.dbparentplanogramkey
    and pog.Value4 = 358 
group by 
    pog.DBKey, pos.DBParentProductKey
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: In addition to the great advice by @marc_s, it also helps if you post test data and expected results for SQL query type questions.

Comment: The implicit-join syntax (comma-delimited `FROM` clause) is considered an anti-pattern.  This would help you spot missing `JOIN` conditions (as @dcp mentions), which is potentially throwing off your results (especially as you don't otherwise appear to use the table...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `pog.DBKey` out of the `GROUP BY`.

Also, I think you are missing a join condition. You have no join condition against table `pro`.

Finally, `DISTINCT` shouldn't be needed.